# Logistic Regression : are updates made at each iteration on the parameter of Newton Raphson method

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, optimization

So basically I want to understand better the Newton Raphson method. I made it through all the matrix calculus and understood how you get to this formula :

[image]

However, are the updates to the beta parameter made after each example of my training set ?

edit : I took this formula from the following paper https://statacumen.com/teach/SC1/SC1_11_LogisticRegression.pdf

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question. This is a iterative method that uses your entire dataset in every iteration (that's the X matrix). The beta parameter is updated after every iteration. Updates to the parameter vector after each example is what Stochastic Gradient Descent does.

Comment: Are you sure that X is a matrix ? I believe it is just a vector of dimension equals to the number of features

Comment: My bad, you are perfectly right, it makes sense now thank you very much